# Windows flickering, lag on window resize

Tags: nvidia, performance, flicker

I have a 3 Years old PC (GeForce GTX570, i7, 16GB RAM, SSD, 2x 24'' LCD monitors) and I installed Ubuntu 15.10 (I also tried with Mint).

Depending on the graphic driver I installed, I got various problems:

- Windows flickering
- Glitches on YouTube videos
- Lag when I resize windows

I installed `htop` and carefully monitored my CPU usage, but nothing is using it much. I guess the problem is that I have an incompatible hardware.

What performances should I expect with Linux? Should the interface be as fluid as Windows is? How to choose a well supported motherboard and graphic card for Linux?

Comment: Have you tried using the proprietary nvidia drivers for linux?

Comment: I tried every single driver on the `Driver Manager`. The 304.131 seems to be the best, but I got flickering when I move windows or when I scroll a page in firefox. Moreover the videos on YouTube are glitchy

Comment: Have you tried running Windows on the computer to make sure your GPU isn't dieing?

Comment: Windows os running fine in dual boot